# How can I use a lookbehind in a regexp inside the awk/gawk action parameter?

Tags: regex

I'm attempting a pretty specific command here.  I have a function that outputs quite a bit of text, like:

```
Country:USA, GDP:984843, id:12345
Country:Spain, GDP:29292, id:23456
Country:Italy, GDP:929393, id:34567
```

That function is called `countries`

So my command is `countries | gawk -v RS='' '/Spain/ {match($0, (/(?<=id:)[0-9]+/), a); print a[0]; exit;}'`

So `countries` gives me the long list of text.

I then use gawk to select the line with `Spain`.

The action(s) once gawk finds the line is `match(...); print a[0]; exit;`, and there is only 1 result with 'Spain' in it, which should be $0, then the regexp part, it should do a positive lookbehind for the substring `id:`, and then match the proceeding numbers and store it in variable a.

Then I want to print out those numbers, however this search fails. It consistently prints nothing.  I know most of the command works, I think it is just a problem with the lookbehind for some reason.  I can remove the lookbehind and incorporate just the search for the first occurrence of the numbers and it successfully returns the first set of numbers

Comment: Does gawk support lookahead or lookbehind? Edit: [doesn't seem it does](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.awk/ZyIw-VMPAZk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to print the ids, wouldn't it be easier to do

```
countries | grep 'Country:Spain' | grep -o '[, ]*id:[0-9]*' | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

If your fields are ordered, it's even easier:

```
countries | grep 'Country:Spain' | cut -d ',' -f 2 | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

Comment: Wouldn't this give me the numbers of every line?  Where does it specify I only want the id from the line containing `Spain`?

Comment: Thanks. I threw out the gawk and went with your first solution and it worked out.